# AWS DMS: Mariadb 10 to Aurora MySQL 5.7 - Migrate and Replicate

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-aurora, dms, aws-dms

Several attempts to migrate and replicate multiple mariadb databases to Aurora mysql failed with a meaningless error:

```
Last Error Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 
[reptask/replicationtask.c:2673] [20014] 
Stop Reason RECOVERABLE_ERROR Error Level RECOVERABLE
```

Migration-only and replication-only tasks wok fine. If I migrate a database and then after first task finished, if I start another replication task, does the replication start the job right where migration finished?

I mean migration can take 3 days. Suppose I start the replication after another 2 days. Does the replication catch up with all the changes during last 5 days?

If not what should I do to ensure data is fully replicated?

I have been unable to fathom the underlying DMS process. Maybe a good document or blog post can help me.

**Update July 16th 2019**

The meaningless error was due to the target endpoint configuration. DMS was unable to drop/truncate a table because other tables data were dependent on it. Setting `initstmt=SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0` fixed the issue: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.MySQL.html